# 2 processes running under postgres user consuming very high cpu

Tags: postgresql, cron

I have a ubuntu server with postgres installed. It is showing me 2 processes running under postgres user. One of them is a cron command and the other tsm.

I have absolutely no idea how they are being executed. I have been trying to google it for hours and I cannot seem to find any references for them.

Any idea where to start looking and how to switch them off  ?

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that you didn't find anything about `cron` if you googled it for hours. I am not sure about `tsm`; could be Tivoli Storage Manager. Use `ps` to find out the executable, and find out to which installation package it belongs. At any rate, both processes are not related to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I did find out about cron itself. I just cannot seem to find out from where this cron job is being executed. There nothing in crontab as such for any user.

Comment: You should ask a Linux system administrator for help. This could have natural causes, but it could also be that someone broke into your system and is abusing it to mine bitcoins.